# Custom array function is not accepting argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I am debugging the code and see that the entites and _deferredKill arrays are correctly populated when erase() is called. The issue is the parameter 'item' is not defined even though I see the argument 'gGameEngine._deferredKill[i]' is being passed in. Why is it not accepting the killed entity I am passing it?  I'm using [simple javascript inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)  by John Resig.

```
//In GameEngine.js
GameEngineClass = Class.extend({

    entities: [],
    _deferredKill: [],

    .........

    for (var k = 0; k < gGameEngine._deferredKill.length; k++){
        gGameEngine.entities.erase(gGameEngine._deferredKill[i]);
    }
}
gGameEngine = new GameEngineClass();

//in core.js, GameEngineClass is extended from this.  
Array.prototype.erase = function(item) {
for (var i = this.length; i--; i) {
    if (this[i] === item) this.splice(i, 1);
}
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the variable `i` when accessing the array index. This variable does not exist and therefore the value of `item` passed as an argument is consequently also `undefined`.

You should replace `gGameEngine._deferredKill[i]` with `gGameEngine._deferredKill[k]` to match your loop.

Comment: Thank you!  I was using 'i' in a previous loop and became blind to the fact that it was out of scope.